# How to parse this type of json using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

Need to parse the JSON to Java Object, how to create a list using comma-separated string as an object example Intrest in the code below.

```
{
  "following": [
    
  ],
  "website": "",
  "name": "Bala",
  "gender": "",
  "interest": [
    "Cricket",
    "FootBall",
    "BasketBall"
  ],
  "isConfirmed": true,
  "posturl": [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com"
  ],
  "age": ""
}
```

Comment: You can try [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) it will generate the corresponding POJOs to parse this input. Also you can see that the `interest` is simply a JSON array containing String values so it will be mapped as `List<String>`.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interest` in the json is not a comma separated String. It is an array. You can map it to `List<String>` type in java object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(String YourJSONObject, JsonObject.class);

## Parsing JSON object ##
JsonArray interestarray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("interest");


## Storing JSONArray elements into Arraylist ##
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
for(JsonElement interest:interestarray){
list.add(interest.getAsString());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please add some detail around you code to explain to the OP what you are doing.